# custom annotations initialization method not working

Tags: java, spring, annotations, customvalidator

Here is my Annotation Class

```
package com.meet.springdemo.mvc.validation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

@Constraint(validatedBy = CourseCodeConstraintValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD } )
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CourseCode {

    // define default course code
    public String value() default "LUV";

    // define default error message
    public String message() default "must start with LUV";

    // define default groups
    public Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    // define default payloads
    public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Here is my constraintValidator class, here I'm trying to validate input string, whether it starts with given prefix or not and return boolean value **true** or **false**.

```
package com.meet.springdemo.mvc.validation;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class CourseCodeConstraintValidator 
    implements ConstraintValidator<CourseCode, String> {

    private String coursePrefix;

    @Override
    public void initialize(CourseCode theCourseCode) {
        coursePrefix = theCourseCode.value();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String theCode, 
                        ConstraintValidatorContext theConstraintValidatorContext) {

        boolean result;

        System.out.println("Course prefix : "+ coursePrefix);
        System.out.println("Course code : "+ theCode);

        if (theCode != null) {
            result = theCode.startsWith(coursePrefix);
        }
        else {
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Here `initialize()` method is not being called up while initialization. And call to `isValid()` prints nothing for `System.out.println("Course prefix : "+ coursePrefix);`.

Lets say, input string `theCode` for `isValid()` is **ABCDEF**;
Then it shows output as:

```
Course prefix : 
Course code : ABCDEF
```

Comment: Where are you using the annotation? In a model on a field / method?

Comment: Using this on a field.

Comment: I posted an answer below with the usage of the `@Valid` annotation, because I think that that is the essential part you are missing in your solution. If something is not clear, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a model which has a couple of fields and you are trying to validate one of the fields called `code` of type String annotated with `@CourseCode`. Let's say the model is called `Course`. So something like:

```
public class Course {

    @CourseCode
    private String code;

    // some other attributes here

    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    // some other getters / setters here
}
```

Java provides an annotation `javax.validation.Valid` which can be used for constraint validating. From the Java docs of the `javax.validation.Valid` annotation:

> Marks a property, method parameter or method return type for validation cascading.
>   Constraints defined on the object and its properties are be validated when the property, method parameter or method return type is validated.
>   This behavior is applied recursively.

So basically you want to apply this `@Valid` annotation on objects you want to have its defined constraints validated. Let's assume you are using the `Course` model in a very basic controller. You could annotate the POSTed `Course` object like so:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class CourseController {

    @PostMapping
    public addNewCourse(@RequestBody @Valid Course newCourse) {
        // perform some persistence logic
    }
}
```

The `@Valid` annotation before `Course newCouse` marks the `newCourse` object as to-be validated, before we enter the `addNewCourse` method.

Now your code should enter the `initialize()` method of `CourseCodeConstraintValidator` and afterwards perform the validation logic from `isValid()`